# Sum and count of grouped records

Tags: sqlite, delphi-10.2-tokyo

Lets say i have a table:

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| R1 | C1 | 5 |
| R2 | C3 | 8 |
| R1 | C1 | 2 |
| R1 | C2 | 4 |
| R2 | C5 | 3 |
| R2 | C2 | 4 |

I need to get:

1. A count of same values of `Col2` with correspondig `Col1` and `SUM`
   of `Col3`.
2. A sum and count of grouped results.

To achive the #1 my code looks like that:

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, COUNT(*), SUM(Col3)
FROM myTable 
GROUP BY Col1, Col2
```

I get the result (and it is ok):

| Col1 | Col2 | Count | Sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| R1 | C1 | 2 | 7 |
| R1 | C2 | 1 | 4 |
| R2 | C2 | 1 | 4 |
| R2 | C3 | 1 | 8 |
| R2 | C5 | 1 | 3 |

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/DIdSRfpU)

For #2 i need to know the `SUM`of values of column `Count` and the `SUM` of values of column `SUM`, where values of column `Col1` are equal. How could i upgrade my code?
The desired result would be something like that:

| Col1 | Col2 | Count | Sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| R1 | C1 | 2 | 7 |
| R1 | C2 | 1 | 4 |
|  |  | 3 | 11 |
| R2 | C2 | 1 | 4 |
| R2 | C3 | 1 | 8 |
| R2 | C5 | 1 | 3 |
|  |  | 3 | 15 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simulate rollup records by adding records, that aggregate only to "*Col1*" values, to your initial result set, using a `UNION ALL` operation.

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, COUNT(*) AS cnt, SUM(Col3) AS total FROM myTable GROUP BY Col1, Col2
UNION ALL 
SELECT Col1, NULL, COUNT(*)       , SUM(Col3)          FROM myTable GROUP BY Col1 
ORDER BY Col1
```

Output:

| Col1 | Col2 | cnt | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| R1 | C1 | 2 | 7 |
| R1 | C2 | 1 | 4 |
| R1 | null | 3 | 11 |
| R2 | C2 | 1 | 4 |
| R2 | C3 | 1 | 8 |
| R2 | C5 | 1 | 3 |
| R2 | null | 3 | 15 |

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/O8FGnnf9).

Comment: Unfortunately delphi gives me different result. Row #3 is missing and last row is:

`R2 null 6 26`

instead of 

#3 `R1 null 3 11`

#7 `R2 null 3 15`

Comment: This solution works in SQLite, and in your fiddle too. Are you sure you're using SQLite?

Comment: yes i am using sqlite. let me do a double check.

Comment: yes, i am positive it is SQLite.

Comment: The reproduced environment in the fiddle shows this solution works in SQLite. Check if tables definition matches yours, and if there's any difference, test this solution with your own tables definitions and data in the fiddle itself.

Comment: the [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/bHbvidrF) with my defitions. works in fidle, but gives different reulst in delphi. something wrong with `UNION ALL`.

Comment: I'm not knowledgeable about the Delphi environment. Can't help you further than SQLite.

Comment: my bad, your answer is correct, i missed `GROUP BY Col1` in the end of line #3 of your code. shame on me.